# coloring variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am starting JavaScript and learning arithmetic operators. I am trying to change the color and size of my variable and the result of it. I am using  in HTML for all of this.

```
var x = window.prompt ("Please enter a number")
var y = window.prompt ("Please enter another number")
var linebreak = "<br>"

document.write("(X - Y) " +  x + " minus " + y + " equals ")
    result = x - y // Subtraction using user inputed variables
    document.write(result) //Shows is the answer
    document.write(linebreak)
```

I have been trying to use css with no luck either:

```
var x {color: green; font-size: 20px;}
var y {color: red; font-size: 20px;}
```

Comment: You cannot change the styling of *variables*. Variables have no style, just values. You can set styles on *HTML elements* into which you may put your values…

Comment: document.write is probably not the best avenue either.  learn to update html with js and you'll be much happier.

Comment: You can wrap your result in a span like `document.write("<span id='result'> result</span>")` and then in your css you can do `#result{color:green}` This way you are styling the contents of the span element (by its `id`), not your variable.

Comment: Hey Convel, please learn the language you want to use and then ask your question again (if you still need to). If you don't know, where to learn, I would advise to do it on sololearn (check out https://www.sololearn.com/Courses/ ). This is a great site for learning to code.

Comment: I have never imagined that someone can even think of coloring variables in JavaScript. My mind just got stumbled. You perhaps want to color the values which you need to put in some HTML tags and do apply some color styles on that tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot style javascript variables as they are not HTML elements. Instead of using document.write, you could create an empty `<p>` tag in your html and use jQuery to replace the text like this:

HTML

```
<p id = "answer"></p>
```

jQuery

```
$("#answer").html(X + "minus" + Y + "equals" + result);
```

Then use CSS to style the `<p>` tag

Comment: Why would you add an entire external library, which is not in the original question, just for something so simple?

Comment: I'm providing an alternative to create the result the question was asking.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help as I am bad at describing what I mean. You were very helpful, I will check more into JQuery and try what you said. As I said I am new to JavaScript and I am very thankful for your tips.